# Error importing trait in to worksheet

Tags: scala

I have the following object and trait definitions in separate files in my package

```
object Bloxorz extends App   // in Bloxorz.scala
trait Solver extends GameDef   // in Solver.scala
trait GameDef                  // in GameDef.scala
```

There is a method in `trait GameDef` I wish to test out. So I create a worksheet in the root of my package and try to import it.

```
import streams.GameDef._
```

But I receive the following error

```
object GameDef is not a member of package streams. Note: trait GameDef exists, but it has no companion object
```

Since `Solver` extends `GameDef`, I figured I needed to import `Solver` instead, but that yielded the same error. Only importing `Bloxorz` object did not throw an error, but that did not expose the method I needed from `GameDef`.

Comment: You mean you did `import` at test suites?

Comment: not the test suite, just a regular scratch worksheet. i already implement tests in BloxorzSuite.scala, but I want a scratch worksheet just to play around, not necessarily formally write tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import streams.GameDef
```

Your code above is importing all classes of a package named GameDef. I'm guessing **G**ameDef is a class,object or trait because it is capitalized. In fact, the error you are getting describes your problem pretty well:

*object GameDef is not a member of package streams. Note: **trait GameDef** exists, but it has no companion object*

Comment: thanks. tried that but the class inside GameDef isn't exposed. i have a `case class Pos(x:Int, y:Int)` in `GameDef`. I try to instantiate this class in the worksheet as `val p = Pos(2,3)` but yields error `not found: type Pos`. i tried extending `GameDef` like `object streamsscratch extends GameDef` but get a flash of error and the worksheet does not evaluate.

Comment: It sounds like `Pos` is an inner class.

Comment: I'm sorry can you please elaborate? What can I do to access this inner class?

Comment: If you try to so this same thing in Java( using eclipse), the error you'll get is pretty descriptive: "No enclosing instance of type GameDef is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type GameDef (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of GameDef)." In other words, to create an instance of Pos, you need to first create an instance of GameDef: `val gd = new GameDef {...}`. You can then create a Pos like this: `val p = new gd.Pos(2,3)`. Rather than exposing Pos, you probably want to be creating an instance of GameDef and testing within it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a shot

Comment: To elaborate a little bit on the reason the inner class cannot be exposed; suppose I have a template class, with an inner class: `class OuterClass[T](val foo:T) {... class InnerClass{
    val bar:T = foo... } }`.  In this case, it would't make sense to create an instance of `Outer.Inner` because T is not specified(i.e. The type of `bar` is not specified). It would stand to reason that a language can either expose it's nested types( statically?) or have template classes and Scala has chosen the latter.

Comment: i tried this but it's not working. what should i put within the braces in `val gd = new GameDef {...}`? Also, in the `import streams.GameDef` there is a warning "imported GameDef is permanently hidden by definition of trait GameDef in package streams"

Comment: `GameDef {...}` should include everything necessary to implement the GameDef trait. `GameDef` probably has member values(`val... = ???`) and definitions(`def... = ???`) that need to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I created code snippet based on what you say and my assumption. I thought you only want to test Pos, not GameDef.

GameDef.scala:

```
package test

trait GameDef {
    case class Pos(x: Int, y: Int) {
         // Pos will play with x and y here.
    }
}
```

YourWorksheet.sc:

```
package test

object TestPosInsideGameDef extends GameDef {
    def newPos(x: Int, y: Int): Pos = new Pos(x, y)

    val pos = newPos(1, 2)
}
```